# AVCaptureSession image size compression like IOS default camera

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios-camera

i have implemented in Xamarin IOS simple app to take picture using AVCaptureSession and AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate.
All work fine, but my problem is the image size.

Using in my code AVCaptureSession.PresetPhoto like session preset in my AVCaptureSession i obtain very big photo size.

After some researches i write my method to obtain the correct format scale.

```
      public UIImage RescaleImage(UIImage img) {
       var format = new UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat();
       format.Scale = 1;
       var renderer = new UIGraphicsImageRenderer(img.Size, format);
       return renderer.CreateImage(c =>  img.Draw(CGPoint.Empty) );
     }
```

After that the size of my photo has the same resolution of IOS camera (3024 x 4032).
Now i should compress image like jpg.
//Image is UIImage

```
                 var jpgImag = Image.AsJPEG(0f);
                 // Converting UIImage to byte[] array
                 Byte[] myByteArray = new Byte[jpgImag.Length];
                 System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(jpgImag.Bytes, 
                    myByteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(jpgImag.Length));
```

Here my capture session code:

```
CaptureSession = new AVCaptureSession();
     CaptureSession.SessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.PresetPhoto;
     CaptureOutput = new AVCapturePhotoOutput();
     CaptureSession.AddOutput(CaptureOutput);
     CaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.GetDefaultDevice(AVMediaType.Video);
     NSError Error;
     // Prepare device for configuration
     if (!CaptureDevice.LockForConfiguration(out Error)) {
        // There has been an issue, abort
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", Error.LocalizedDescription);
        CaptureDevice.UnlockForConfiguration();
        return;
     }
     CaptureDevice.FocusMode = AVCaptureFocusMode.ContinuousAutoFocus;
     // Unlock configuration
     CaptureDevice.UnlockForConfiguration();
     CaptureDeviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.FromDevice(CaptureDevice);
     CaptureSession.AddInput(CaptureDeviceInput);
```

My settings:

```
  var settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings.Create();
        var previewPixelType = settings.AvailablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.First();
        settings.PreviewPhotoFormat = new NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>(CVPixelBuffer.PixelFormatTypeKey, settings.AvailablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes[0]);
        settings.FlashMode = AVCaptureFlashMode.Auto;
        return settings;
```

If i save myByteArray i obtain a 20MB file for example. If i shoot same photo with ios camera i obtain 3MB image (for example).

The only difference between 2 images is the Bit depth.
My app is 32. IOS camera 24
And dpi
My app is 96. IOS camera 72

My question is:

how can set my AVCaptureSession to obtain more similar result like IOS camera?
(swift code is fine too)

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to use `CVPixelFormatType.CV24BGRA` when you create a VideoDataOutput and add it to your sesion.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I will write the code to set my Session in my post.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT in AVCapturePhotoOutput where can i set the CVPixelFormatType?

Comment: Something like    `var output = new AVCaptureVideoDataOutput ();`
    `var settings = new AVVideoSettingsUncompressed ();`
    `settings.PixelFormatType = CVPixelFormatType.CV32BGRA;`,refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/intro-to-manual-camera-controls#creating-an-av-capture-session

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT , i don't use AVVideoSettingsUncompressed but AVCapturePhotoSettings. I try the example in you link, but exception occured:
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: *** -[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput setVideoSettings:] Unsupported pixel format type - use -availableVideoCVPixelFormatTypes

Comment: Perhaps you could check the documentation for native development to see if there are any relevant Settings.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT i try, but I did not find anything that works fine :(

Comment: Maybe you could try to compress image after take the photo.